# How do I configure FFserver+FFmpeg to fetch a live stream in one format and output it in another?

Tags: streaming, ffmpeg

I've got an IP camera on a 3G modem. I need to fetch its stream from a landline server and re-stream it.

Right now the only cheap option seems to be FFserver (but feel free to suggest others), but I'm not really sure where to start... Does anyone have any experience using FFserver?

Answer (score 2):

I did just about 1 day ago. ffmpeg can't really handle live feeds so you must make a pipe and stream through it. I guess you already have ffmpeg installed, also install mplayer.

Do this:

```
mkfifo somename.someext
ffmpeg -i somename.someext http://localhost:yourport/yourfeed
```

Open another terminal and do this:

```
mplayer -streamdump protocol://ipofcamera -dumpfile somename.someext
```

And... that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help http://freakingtips.com/2009/07/23/online-video-streaming-on-ubuntu/.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try vlc (they have good streaming howto)
and if You need RTMP (for flash client) look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669308/best-way-for-live-rtmp-streaming-from-dv-camcorder.